# Morphia Mongodb searching an array of string

Tags: java, mongodb, morphia

I was trying to write a query criteria using Morphis for something like:

```
db.Response.find( { $and: [ { fields: [ "NAME","EMAIL"]},{intent:"CHECKUSR" }] } )
```

Can you help me with this? The problem here is I need to check with a array called fields, and the above query in working in MongoDB, but not able to find a suitable option in morphia for this.
Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: i can help you if you can give me the actual structure of your document.

Comment: Since it is not allowing to post the entire content here; i posted as an answer to the main topic. Please scroll down

Answer (score 0):

```
Datastore ds = ...
Query<Record> q = ds.createQuery(Record.class);
q.and(
    q.criteria("Intent").equal(CHECKUSR),
    q.criteria("fields.email").equal(EMAIL)
);

//list
List<Record> entities = q.asList();
```

another approach would be

```
Query q = ds.createQuery(Record.class).field("fields").hasThisElement(email);
```

this basically is an example on how you can write your criteria. You can tweak it for your purpose.

in the above samples Record is a class representing your document

Comment: Thanks Satish, but one issue is here isnt it? For me, "fields" is the field in document and ["name", "email"] are two string array elements. so your suggestion will not try to compare.

Comment: so what you mean is you have a document {_id: someid, x: xvalue, y:yvalue, fields:["someonename","someoneemailid"]} right ? and you need to query the fields based on the name and email values ?

Comment: Just added the whole scenario below.. Please have a look. thanks much

Comment: Yes Satish, i need to query based on name and email id. It is possible using the "db.document.find( { $and: [ { fields: [ "NAME","EMAIL"]},{intent:"CHECKUSR" }] } )". But not happening using morphia.

Comment: 1. create a string array called filterValues.

2. assign name and email to this filterValues Arrays
filterValues[0] = name;
filterValues[1] = email;


then 

Query q = ds.createQuery(USERSETUP.class).field("fields").hasAllOf(Arrays.asList(filterValues));
List<USERSETUP> entities = q.asList();

USERSETUP should be replaced by your actual represntation of the document class.